# Why are bang methods dangerous in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, coding-style, naming-conventions

I've been re-learning Ruby lately, and [this](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/writing_own_ruby_methods.html) page says that usually a bang method is dangerous, but it doesn't say why. Why are bang methods dangerous?

Comment: To add to the answerers' answers - when you create your own classes make sure to use the same convention.

Comment: Bang methods modify the receiver and always have non-bang counterparts that do not, but there are many non-bang methods that also modify the receiver. Is it OK to modify the receiver? Certainly! Sometimes there are enormous performance gains (as well as reduced memory requirements) by doing so. As an example, suppose we wish to append an array `a` with the elements of a second array `b`. Let's do a benchmark of two methods: `require 'fruity'; a = [0]*1_000_000; b = a.dup; compare do { a_plus_b { a = a+b }; concat { a.concat(b) }; end
  #=>concat is faster than a_plus_b by 30x ± 10.0`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two widespread meanings of "dangerous" in standard library and common gems:

1. Method mutates the receiver, as opposed to returning a copy of the receiver. Example: `Array#map!`
2. Method will raise an exception if its primary function can't be performed. Example: `ActiveRecord::Base#save!`, `ActiveRecord::Base#create!`. If, say, an object can't be saved (because it's not valid or whatever), `save!` will raise an error, while `save` will return `false`.

I usually add a third meaning to it in my code:

3. Method will immediately persist data in the database, instead of just changing some attributes and hoping that later someone will save the object. Example: hypothetical `Article#approve!`

Comment: There's also `Process::exit!` which skips running exit handlers, as opposed to `Process::exit` which runs them normally.

Comment: Why are methods that mutate the receiver more dangerous than those that return a copy? The reason has to do with mutability vs immutability; the former results in a state change that's generally more difficult to reason about than immutability. Ideally, functions should be pure and idempotent, and bang methods typically aren't.

Answer (score 3):

The page you refer to includes this:

> Normally for the built-in classes, dangerous usually (although not always) means this method, unlike its non-bang equivalent, permanently modifies its receiver.

Comment: I must have missed that when I was reading. Thanks! I'll accept this when it allows me.

Answer (score 2):

The convention goes like this:

- Firstly, you create a bang method only if you have a non-bang alternative with the same name.
- Secondly - yes, it means that this version is "more dangerous". This is a very vague term as you said yourself.
- In a lot of the standard library it will modify an object in place, instead of creating a new one. Sometimes it will return `nil` instead of the object if the call didn't require any modification.
- In rails bang methods usually raise exceptions as opposed to returning `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

> Why are bang methods dangerous?

Because that's the naming convention: if there are two methods which do the same thing, then you name them both the same name but the more surprising or more dangerous one gets the bang.

For example, [`Process::exit`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Process.html#method-c-exit) and [`Process::exit!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Process.html#method-c-exit-21) both exit the currently running Ruby process, but the bang version will skip running all exit handlers that may be installed, and so, for example, skip any cleanup that you might have scheduled for when your app exits.

Answer (score -3):

No it is not dangerous. Bang methods simply means they are modifying the object itself and you should be careful.

Comment: That page said so too, but it also said, and I quote, `By convention, the bang labels a method as dangerous...` Is that just an opinion?

Comment: @Reggie Is that an official page? If not, then it is a personal opinion.

Comment: Yes, Ruby uses a lot of naming conventions, not all of them are enforced. By convention, methods that modify the receiver (instead of creating a new object) have names ending in "!". Library implementors are expected to follow the convention, but there is nothing in the language to enforce that.

Comment: This is wrong. Bang method means that it is a more surprising or more dangerous variant of its corresponding non-bang method. Modifying the receiver may or may not be the cause of its being more dangerous, but that is just coincidence. For example, `Kernel#exit!` doesn't modify anything, OTOH, `Array#clear` mutates the receiver but doesn't have a bang (because there is no corresponding less dangerous method).